Parse a fixed width file using Apache Beam and Java
Does Apache Beam Java SDK provide transforms out-of-the-box to parse a fixed width file? Also, can we provide the fixed-wdth parsing configuration (like range and field name) using a config/json file in Apache Beam?
I'm trying to avoid writing fixed width parsing logic in DoFn and ParDo.
I've gone through the transform documentations for apache beam at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms.

HI , if you don't want to use Dofn and Pardo , maybe it's possible using  File-based input and output data .Look at this doc once .

Could you clarify what a fixed width file is ? If it's just a general text or binary file with fixed records, have you considered using Beam FileIO or TextIO ?

@chamikara A fixed width file is a general text file with a defined column range for different attributes. There is no delimiter between different values, you'd have to extract substring based on start and end range to get the attribute value. Fixed width files have a fixed number of columns. The file I'm trying to process has a lot of attributes (5000 characters per row). I can build custom logic to parse this file using Java substring with FileIO and TextIO. I wanted to check if Beam has a functionality to create a Java bean for the records using provide name and range configuration.
